# the Class of Ordinals is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Why the class of ordinals On is not a set?

Please dont tell me it's well-ordered till you tell me what you mean by an ordering on 
something that you dont know in first place if it is a set or not.

Answer (score 5):

We don't need to know that something is a set in order to order it.

Formally speaking if $A$ is a class we can define an order on $A$ to be another class $R$ such that $z\in R$ means that $z=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $x,y\in A$, and moreover $R$ satisfies the axioms of an ordered set (whichever you prefer them to be, irreflexive and transitive; or reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive).

Now we can say that $\in\upharpoonright\sf Ord\times Ord$ is a well-ordering of $\sf Ord$.

---

But if we assume that $\sf Ord$ is a set then we can show that it is in fact an ordinal itself, therefore $\sf Ord\in Ord$. However this means that $\sf Ord$ is not well-founded, because $\{\sf Ord\}$ is a non-empty subset without a minimal element!

Comment: An alternative to the last sentence would be to say that $\text{Ord}$ has an element $x$ (namely $x = \text{Ord}$) such that $x \in x$, contradicting irreflexivity of $\in$ on $\text{Ord}$.

Comment: True. That's a nicer touch, I think.

Comment: When you wrote “irreflexive and transitive“ I guess you meant “asymmetric and transitive”? Because $\ne$ is clearly irreflexive and transitive, but definitely not an order.

Comment: @celtschk: Is it, though? $x\neq y$ and $y\neq x$, by transitivity $x\neq x$? No. Anyway, I meant what I wrote. Irreflexive and transitive. Though some people use the term antireflexive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Indeed, it's not transitive; I was too fast on this. I see now that irreflexivity and transitivity already imply asymmetry. So it's more a matter of taste which of them one demands (though I still prefer asymmetry in the definition, as it more directly indicates the important part making it an order; note that without transitivity, asymmetry indeed is a stronger property than irreflexivity).

Comment: @celtschk: The standard definition of a partial order is either reflexive/antisymmetric/transitive or irreflexive/transitive. Depends on whether or not you want this to be a reflexive one.

Comment: Define “standard”. When two sets of axioms are completely equivalent, then it is purely a matter of taste which of them one chooses, isn't it?

Comment: @celtschk: The one that appears pretty much everywhere I've looked, and having been a set theorist for a while, I looked in all the standard sources?

Comment: At least https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Strict_Ordering lists both axiom sets, and my preferred one first. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictOrder.html lists all three conditions as axioms, but notes that not all three are needed. Those two resources alone should be sufficient evidence that not using asymmetry in the definition is definitely not universal. To decide which definition is more common would require a statistical analysis of many books; but I'm pretty sure had I come across a definition not using asymmetry or antisymmetry before, I'd surely remember.

Answer (score 1):

Assume On is a set. Then it is well-ordered and transitive, hence an ordinal and an element of itself, contradicting its own wellorder.

Comment: By the way, it's not at all obvious (in my opinion, anyway) that the class of ordinals is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$ (even though it might seem so at first glance because of the resemblance to the definition of "ordinal.")  Same comment applies to Asaf's answer of course.

Comment: When you wrote "... contradicting its own wellorder" here, did you mean to write "contradicting its own well-foundedness"? I don't see well-orderedness being contradicted here.